# UWP PointerEnter and PointerLeave not attached to the outer element in the tree

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, custom-controls

I've created a custom control in which I want to change state according to the PointerEnter and PointerLeave events. 
The problem is that those events are triggered on the Border which is a child of a Grid.
I expect the Grid to trigger those events.

my custom control

```
public sealed class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomControl);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnPointerEntered(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Enter");
        base.OnPointerEntered(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPointerExited(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPointerExited(e);
        Trace.WriteLine("Exit");
    }
}
```

and its template

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
                    <Grid Padding="50">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="bdr"
                            Margin="50"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <TextBox
                                x:Name="_txt"
                                Height="50"
                                Margin="25"
                                FontSize="18"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Border>                    
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and I'm calling it with

```
<myCustomControl:MyCustomControl
    BorderBrush="Green"
    BorderThickness="3"
    Text="Test" />
```

As I mentioned, for some reason the PointerEnter and PointerLeave are bound to the Border element.

A weird patch is that if I add a Background property to the Grid, then those events are bound to the Grid, but it's not right.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that those events are triggered on the Border which is a child of a Grid. I expect the Grid to trigger those events.

The problem is that you do not set the Grid's `Background` property. Please try the following style.

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="RootGrid"
                    Padding="50"
                    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    >
                    <Border
                        x:Name="bdr"
                        Margin="50"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                        <TextBox
                            x:Name="_txt"
                            Height="50"
                            Margin="25"
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: this is what I was saying... but can you explain why do I have to set the Grid's background at first place ?

Comment: You could regard the Grid as Lazy load control. if don't set bg color property, the content air will be regard as empty.